# IIS Rewrite for Specified Url And Port not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Im trying to handle IIS Rewrite for Specific website and port.

This is my Setting in web.config (Im Using Asp.net MVC)

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(https?:\/\/)?127\.0\.0\.1:80\/?$" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://google.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

and when i call address http://127.0.0.1 it should redicret me to google but it wont.

if i change it like this it works :

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=(.*) />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://google.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

the pattren works perfectly on my inbound rule :

[image]

adding condition also didnt help :

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(https?:\/\/)?127\.0\.0\.1:80\/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(https?:\/\/)?127\.0\.0\.1:80\/?$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://google.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

ive enabled the FRT to check log and it shows this :

```
<failedRequest url="http://127.0.0.1:80/" siteId="1" appPoolId="DefaultAppPool" 
processId="8432" verb="GET" remoteUserName="" userName="" tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" 
authenticationType="anonymous" activityId="{800008BA-0001-E700-B63F-84710C7967BB}" 
failureReason="STATUS_CODE" statusCode="302" triggerStatusCode="302" timeTaken="0" 
xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
```

Comment: Learn what are the common mistakes one can make in rewrite rules and you can avoid them, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @LexLi Very helpful link. the problem was with the url catching.

Answer (score 1):

you could try below rule:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="127.0.0.1" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.com" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

With @LexLi Link i was able to fix it with this :

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
             
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com"  appendQueryString="false"/>
             
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```